# Topology, open sets?

Tags: general-topology

If $(X,d)$ is a metric space, $X=\{1,2\}$ and a topology $T=\{ ∅,\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$. Is it correct to say that each element of $T$ is an open set of $X$, for any $d$? **What if $X$ had no metric at all?**

Comment: $T$ is not a topology; it is missing $\emptyset$.

Comment: @Benjamin You beat me to this comment by a few seconds...are...are we the same person?

Comment: I thought all sets automatically had the empty set

Comment: @minusatwelfth :It is true that $\emptyset \subset T$ for any set $T$, but not true that $\emptyset \in T$ for any set $T$.

Comment: Thanks, i realise that now :)

Comment: @BenS. You are both Bens..

Comment: @BenS. .... maybe

Comment: Technically, $1$ isn't an open set, but $\{1\}$ is. This is a bit pedantic, though.

Answer (score 4):

Once you include the empty set as suggested in the comments, this is a topology. In particular, this is the discrete topology. In general, metrics on finite sets are a little strange. One such metric that could be used to generate the discrete topology on any set (including finite ones) is the (obviously enough) discrete metric.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space

You can prove actually that finite metric spaces are discrete. This is a good exercise. Try examining what happens for different size balls at different points.

It's worth nothing that the topology is somehow prior to the metric though. That is to say, topological structure doesn't require metric structure, but a particular topological structure might coincide or be induced with/by a metric.

Comment: This does not answer my question

Comment: @minusatwelfth I'm sorry, I thought this was clear. It is by definition true that every member of a topology is open. This is exactly what it means to be open. Surely the question regarding the distances is what I'm describing as the discrete metric.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that if $(X, d)$ is metric space and $X$ is finite, then all sets in $X$ are open:

For each $a\in X$. Let $r = \frac 12 \min_{x\in X} d(a, x) >0$. Then

$$\{a\} = B(a, r)$$

is open in $X$. Actually all [$T_1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space) finite space has this property.

If $X$ has no metric and has more than one element, it might not be (think of trivial topology).

Comment: Thanks, is there a finite set X (without a metric) that has a topology s.t. the elements of T are open sets?

Comment: You need only to show that $\{a\}$ is in $T$, that's because all unions of open sets are open, so in this case every subset of $T$ are open. @minusatwelfth

Comment: Sorry i made my edit late, but what if there was no metric?

Comment: . Oh, then yes. The $T$ you write in your question is a topology on $X$. Then it is by definition that all elements in $T$ are open. (Note that to define a topology, you do not need a metric). @minusatwelfth

Comment: Interesting. Last question, how can I test whether or not whether each element is an open set? Because as you said, there may be exceptions like the trivial topology

Comment: If nothing is known about the topology of $X$, there is no way to check which subset of $X$ are indeed open in $X$. In my answer, I can show that are subsets are open, since I know that the topology of $X$ is given by a metric. But in general, no. @minusatwelfth

Comment: I thought any element of T is considered an open set though, for any topology T

Comment: A topology on $X$ is a family of subset ( call $T$) of $X$. There might be different $T$ given to $X$, which corresponds to different topologies on $X$. If $T$ is not known, then we do not know which subset of $X$ are in $T$, thus not know which subset of $X$ are open. (Yes, it is the terminology that elements in $T$ are called open. To be precise, it's called open in the topology $T$) @minusatwelfth

Comment: but according to what you said, even if T is not known, we should still know that its elements are open sets no matter what? at least that's what it says here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_topology#A_topology_on_a_set

Comment: The defintion is: an subset $S$ in a topological space $(X, T)$ is called open if and only if $S\in T$. That's all I want to say. @minusatwelfth